# formating issue with list of integers [TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to sort an odd number without changing the position of even number 
while considering zero as even.

I tried to solve using lazy way but there was a weird issue about formatting issue 
please check code below:

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    result = source_array[:]
    odd = []
    for i in result :
        if i % 2 == 0 or i == 0:
            odd.append('even_number')
        else:
            odd.append(i)
            result[i] = 'odd'

     # this is not a complete implementation we need to sort odd then replace it 
     # string 'even_number' kind off merge
    return source_array
#checking the out put below
print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))
print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]) == [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4])
```

I got the output below

> File "sort_even_number.py", line 48, in
>
> ```
> print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))   File "sort_even_number.py", line 40, in sort_array
>
> if i % 2 == 0 or i == 0:
> ```
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0):

In python we usually use `i` variable for index. Here you iterate over list and those are list elements, not indexes. `for i in result :`

So each list element is an integer but not an index. It happens that it's a valid index as well, as indexes are integers.

At some point the variables are

```
odd = [5, 3, 'even_number']
result = [5, 3, 2, 'odd', 1, 'odd']
```

There are a few problems with your script. The source of error is this. `result[i] = 'odd'`

No idea if you do that on purpose but it would be easier if you didn't edit an iterable while you iterate over it. And you can't do modulo of a string (`'odd'`).

I think you will crack the rest of it yourself.

Comment: i was blind for this after fixing it to iterate over indexes it's works, thank you